# how to show a floating action button always in bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [material ui](https://material-ui.com/)

I have a floating action button and I want to show it a specific place that would not change with scroll,

and also I want to know if it is a fine problem

here is the code

```
  const floatingMenuButtonStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#DEEAF6',
    color: '#8A3473',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: '8%',
    right: '9%'
```

here is floating action button

```
   <Fab 
        style={floatingMenuButtonStyle}
         aria-label="add"
          children={<AddIcon fontSize='default' />}></Fab>
      }
```

Comment: I don't think `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` works with `position: 'fixed'`. - It looks like you have multiple scrolling elements, and the one inside is bigger than the viewport. It looks like the button is aligned to that rather than the viewport

Comment: i just tried this, but it returns the same

Comment: Without a runnable [mcve] I can't help further

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The html and css does it well like this.

All you need to do is to simply parent it in a `<div>` element with `position:fixed` and then next your icon as a child with `position:absolute` and it gets positioned at the bottom right as you wanted.

just like this sample green box

```
<div style="
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;">

    <div style="
        width:130px;
        height:130px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color:green;">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks this was helpful, although it looks differently in jsx

Comment: If the styles are moved out, it will be the same. You may use react way of style assigning or simply You can assign a class or id for the <div> elements and write the CSS code in a separate .css file where you write those styles.